# Reattaching waterproof rubber on GPS

Tags: gear-care, gps

The black waterproof rubber seal round my Garmin etrex h has just started to peel away, and while not a major issue at the moment I don't really want to use it in the rough when it's waterproofing is compromised.

What's the best way to reattach the seal? Would normal epoxy be fine, or are there any special considerations I should be aware of?

Comment: Could you attach a picture, please?  Do you have any information on the specific composition of the materials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably wouldn't use regular epoxy. I have had trouble with it on rubber around water. When I am trying to reseal rubber I use [silicone sealant](http://www.swimoutlet.com/product_p/40027.htm) or  [seal cement](http://www.loctiteproducts.com/p/cntct_silicone/overview/Loctite-Clear-Silicone-Waterproof-Sealant.htm) or [Super under water epoxy](http://www.loctiteproducts.com/p/epxy_mrn_s/overview/Loctite-Epoxy-Marine.htm).

The seal cement is neoprene but it dries waterproof.

Any one should work just fine it only depends on what you use the GPS for. Obviously the 3000 PSI rated epoxy that dries underwater would be the strongest but I would worry about it cracking or drying out if it is rarely or never under water. I usually have no problem with the silicone sealant for most things and use the seal cement on clothing only.